# If "anything other than a positive number" in a specific range of cells, stop macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie in VBA and I would like to see if anyone can help me out with this one.

What I want this macro to do is to see if any cells between A1 and J12 in my worksheet has a negative number or a letter. If it does, I want it to prompt a MsgBox "Only positive numbers allowed, please fix" and then stop the macro.

The only way I was able to reach this objective was by using the following:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("A1")) Or sht2.Range("A1") < 0 Then MsgBox ("Only positive numbers allowed, please fix")

Exit Sub
```

However, if I do it this method, I need to basically add one line of code for every cell I want this rule to apply. I have tried replacing "A1" to "A1:J12" but for some reason VBA won't accept this and gives me "Run-Time Error '13', Type Mismatch."

So basically, my question is, is there a more efficient way to achieve this which does not involve a line of code for every single cell?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = sh2.Range("A1:J12")

If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=0") <> rng.Count Then
   MsgBox "Uh-oh, something other than a nonnegative number"
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Here's how this works:

- `CountIfs` returns the count of values >= 0 in `rng`.
- `.Count` returns the number of cells in `rng`.

If the two aren't equal, then something's off (blanks, text, negative values, etc.)

Caveat(s):

- This won't work if `rng` has multiple areas, for example if `rng` corresponds to `sh2.Range("A1:A3,C4:C5")`. You'll get a

  > RTE 1004: Unable to get the CountIfs property of the  WorksheetFunction class.

  That will require a loop.

Comment: I am confused: does `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=0")` count strings aswell? - because catching strings is also required. But if it does that leaves another problem since a negative number will increase `Count` but not `CountIfs` and a string will not increase `count` but would increase `CountIfs` so if both banned inputs were present at equal amounts the code would think everything is fine (even though it wouldn't be) - but I don't believe the `CountIfs` counts strings to begin with

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII - I tested in a worksheet. `>=0` seemed to only include numbers.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, it worked like a charm. 

The issue is that I don't know what you did there, can you please point me to any keyword so I can look up what you just did in that code? I would like to learn about it.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII - also note that `.Count` here is not equivalent to `WorksheetFunction.Count`.

Comment: @BigBen yeah that's where my mistake was - I was thinking about of the functionality of the Worksheet Function - thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Reading at @Lord-JulianXLII 's reply got me worried now, will it give me a false positive? I ask because I basically copy pasted the code.

Comment: @EricAhn no it will work perfectly fine - I got 2 functions with the same name mixed up

Comment: @EricAhn I added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: loop over the Cells of a Range.

The `Cells` property of a Range object is a collection of all the Cells in said Range. You can easily loop over a collection of items and perform certain actions/statements for each item.

For example:

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J12").Cells
  'code here will be executed for every cell in the collection
  Debug.Print IsNumeric(cell.value)
Next cell
```

You can read more on looping over ranges here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells

Comment: Side note, the `.Cells` is redundant here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will make sure I learn about loops, I took a quick look and it seems like something I might use in the very near future.